# Django Jquery mysterious error

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, jquery-plugins

I'm using jquery form plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm to upload images through ajax to serverside programmed in Django. When the image is uploaded I use this jquery plugin http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ to set the fullpage background with that image. The image gets uploaded and stored but the image is not displayed as a background.

It shows this error:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cover/'http://localhost:8000/files/backgrounds/2_17.jpg'
404 NOT FOUND
```

But when I hardcode the url like this for example: (for checking)

```
$.backstretch('http://localhost:8000/files/backgrounds/2_17.jpg')
```

It shows the background. what is the problem here? The responseText(response from django is the correct address as above
ie

```
 'http://localhost:8000/files/backgrounds/2_17.jpg'
```

Javascript code:
https://gist.github.com/2382470

Django views.py:
https://gist.github.com/2382475

Django settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/files/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/nirmal/try/files/'
```

Django urls.py:

```
url(r'^cover/$', 'cover.views.backgroundview'),
```

What would be the mistake here? Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The image URL is wrong

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cover/'http://localhost:8000/files/backgrounds/2_17.jpg'
```

It should not contain the `'` and not have two `http://` bits in it.

See the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cover/` bit -- check if you are running

```
python manage.py runserver localhost:8000
```

Also, inside your Django view code, you can drop the `'` wrapping as `g.background.url` is already a string:

```
return HttpResponse(g.background.url)
```

Comment: I knew it. But the response url from django is correct like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/backgrounds/2_17.jpg so where is the mistake?

Comment: How the response string from django is perfect but when using in the $.backstretch(responseText) it shows wrong url?

Comment: That's the interesting question :)